# How do I upsert a record in ADO.NET EF 4.1?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I'm trying to accomplish something really simple and I can't find how to do it using Entity Framework 4.1.

I want a controller method that accepts an object and then does an UPSERT (either an insert or update depending on whether the record exists in the database).

I am using a natural key, so there's no way for me to look at my POCO and tell if it's new or not.

This is how I am doing it, and it seems wrong to me:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveMyEntity(MyEntity entity)
{            
    MyContainer db = new MyContainer(); // DbContext
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var existing =
            db.MyEntitys.Find(entity.MyKey);
        if (existing == null)
        {
            db.MyEntitys.Add(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            existing.A = entity.A;
            existing.B = entity.B;
            db.Entry(existing).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(new { Result = "Success" });
    }
}
```

Ideally, the whole thing would just be something like this:

```
db.MyEntities.AddOrModify(entity);
```

Comment: What happens when you do only `Save` ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this without querying database or using stored procedure. The minimalistic code should be:

```
public void AddOrModify<T>(T entity, string key) where T : class, IEntity // Implements MyKey 
{
     using (var context = new MyContainer())
     {
         if (context.Set<T>().Any(e => e.MyKey == key))
         {
              context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
         } 
         else
         {
              context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
         }

         context.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

Comment: This works.  The Sql emitted by the framework isn't ideal, but at least it saves me the trouble of setting the fields manually when an update is required.  Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend that you stress test this for race conditions (See SP suggestions below).

Comment: You can perform collision detection on either side of the wire as long as you ensure atomicity with a transaction. This is especially important when you work over multiple data stores. A server-side solution should always be more efficient, but not required. This answer is probably one of the cleanest examples of doing an upsert via DbContext API.

Comment: What happens when you do only `Save` ?

Comment: This method looks improperly named to me.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka, what if by convention, we always use `Id` as the key? Is there anyway not to implement `IEntity`?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati: You must use the convention to actually make the approach with IEntity work. Without IEntity you would need to use reflection which is wrong and slow approach.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases you do not need to explicitly set the `EntityState.Modified` unless you've disabled change tracking.

The solution we took was to check the value of the entity identifier:

```
if (entity.Id == default(int)) {
    // transient entity so insert
} else {
    // update
}
```

Comment: This solution won't work for me, since I'm not using an integer identity key.  I'm using a natural composite key, so there's no way for me to look at my POCO and tell if it's new or not.

Comment: Then hitting the database to check seems like the only viable solution for you. It would be better to have clearly defined actions for insert/update and really you should be using viewmodels, but I appreciate this is probably a simple example.

Comment: You can consider caching a (threadsafe) set of used identifiers and update it after every insert/delete operation (unless You can change a key, but that is very wrong in my opinion) to speed up a process, but If You are not using autogenerated key (which are the way to go, why don't You use them, You don't have to drop You key, u can even index it with unique constraint) that's the only way I see (handling duplicate key exception is not really the way:D)

Comment: @luckyluke Wrong, you should ALWAYS handle duplicate key exception, unless you're always writing to the database from a single thread. Otherwise you will always have a race condition when using EF, because it doesn't support the MERGE SQL operation.

Answer (score 2):

actually there is a way to informa db context that entity you are trying to insert is changed and now the new one

```
_context.MyEntity.Attach(entity);
_context.MyEntity(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
```

Answer (score 2):

To perform an UPSERT operation, You might want to consider creating an SP that performs a MERGE.

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3739131/UPSERT-Functionality-in-SQL-Server-2008.htm

Whatever way you choose the operation must be atomic or you'll have a race condition.
Your SP will probably need a HOLDLOCK to void this ...

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx

Comment: What happens when you do only `Save` ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old and has an accepted answer, but I think there is a better solution: it doesn't require an extra interface to be implemented or key type to be defined.

```
public static class DbSetExtensions
{
    public static EntityEntry<TEnt> AddIfNotExists<TEnt, TKey>(this DbSet<TEnt> dbSet, TEnt entity, Func<TEnt, TKey> predicate) where TEnt : class
    {
        var exists = dbSet.Any(c => predicate(entity).Equals(predicate(c)));
        return exists
            ? null
            : dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public static void AddRangeIfNotExists<TEnt, TKey>(this DbSet<TEnt> dbSet, IEnumerable<TEnt> entities, Func<TEnt, TKey> predicate) where TEnt : class
    {
        var entitiesExist = from ent in dbSet
            where entities.Any(add => predicate(ent).Equals(predicate(add)))
            select ent;

        dbSet.AddRange(entities.Except(entitiesExist));
    }
}
```

So later it can be used like this:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var user1 = new User { Name = "Peter", Age = 32 };
    context.Users.AddIfNotExists(user1, u => u.Name);

    var user2 = new User { Name = "Joe", Age = 25 };
    context.Users.AddIfNotExists(user2, u => u.Age);

    // Adds user1 if there is no user with name "Peter"
    // Adds user2 if there is no user with age 25
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: @GertArnold no actually I was looking for an "UPSERT" or "INSERT or do nothing if the entity already exists", but all the solutions I found asked to implement interfaces or use specialized method for every entity type etc.
So I created this generic method which I'm using in my application and yes, it works.

Comment: It works? The code doesn't even compile! And if it does you'll get "The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."

Comment: @GertArnold probably it depends on the version of VS & C# (I'm using VS 2017 Community and C# 7.1) and .NET Framework & EntityFramework library. Indeed I'm not using EF 4.1 like it was in the OP back in 2011.
What EF version are you using (what about .NET is it "Full" Framework or Core?)

Comment: You are obviously targeting ef-core, which is quite different from ef 4.1 - 6 as should be expected from the question. However, even for ef-core this is a bad solution because it forces client-side evaluation, i.e. the whole table is pulled into memory before the predicate is applied.