# Update an item but insert if it does not exists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

How can I update an item but insert it if it does not exists in my context? Is there any command for that or I really need to do 2 passes?

something like

```
context.Users.UpdateOrInsert(user);
```

or i will have to do a classic

```
// pseudo code
if (context.Users.Any(user))
    context.users.Update(user)
else
    context.Users.Add(user);
```

Comment: I don't know if it will work for you, but there is a `AddOrUpdate` method that I use when doing migrations.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.idbsetextensions.addorupdate(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510908/how-do-i-upsert-a-record-in-ado-net-ef-4-1

Comment: @cadrell0 that's good to know with EF5  +1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I upsert a record in ADO.NET EF 4.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510908/how-do-i-upsert-a-record-in-ado-net-ef-4-1)