# How to insert update multiple data in DB through Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Suppose I have few records which i want to insert/update through EF.

```
public partial class Contact
{
        public int ContactID { get; set; }
        public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
        public string EmailID { get; set; }
}

var _Contact = new list<Contact>();
_Contact.add(new Contact(){ContactID=1,ContactPerson="Dev",EmailID="d@gmail.com"});
_Contact.add(new Contact(){ContactID=2,ContactPerson="Ross",EmailID="a@gmail.com"});
_Contact.add(new Contact(){ContactID=3,ContactPerson="Martin",EmailID="b@gmail.com"});
_Contact.add(new Contact(){ContactID=4,ContactPerson="Moss",EmailID="c@gmail.com"});
_Contact.add(new Contact(){ContactID=5,ContactPerson="Koos",EmailID="q@gmail.com"});
```

With the help of a stored procedure, we can detect that any particular records exist or not, if exist then update will execute and if not exist then records will be inserted. i want to do the same through EF.......is it possible ?

I know that I can call SQL Server stored procedures from EF to achieve my goal but I am trying to know if I can do it in EF without calling a stored procedure?

If yes then discuss the same with sample code which check each records exist in db or not and if exist then it will update otherwise will insert. Looking for help.

Comment: How do you check that record already exists in DB? What is equality for records, `ContactID`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I upsert a record in ADO.NET EF 4.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510908/how-do-i-upsert-a-record-in-ado-net-ef-4-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since EF 4.3 there is an AddOrUpdate ExtensionMethod for DbSet. in Namespace System.Data.Entity.Migrations

```
public partial class Contact
{
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
    public string EmailID { get; set; }
}

var _Contact=new list<Contact>();
_Contact.add(new Contact(){ContactID=1,ContactPerson="Dev",EmailID="d@gmail.com"});
_Contact.add(new Contact(){ContactID=2,ContactPerson="Ross",EmailID="a@gmail.com"});
_Contact.add(new Contact(){ContactID=3,ContactPerson="Martin",EmailID="b@gmail.com"});
_Contact.add(new Contact(){ContactID=4,ContactPerson="Moss",EmailID="c@gmail.com"});
_Contact.add(new Contact(){ContactID=5,ContactPerson="Koos",EmailID="q@gmail.com"});

// check by Primary key
context.Contacts.AddOrUpdate(_Contacts)
// or check by EmailID
context.Contacts.AddOrUpdate(p => p.EmailID, _Contacts)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but if i need to see what SQL AddOrUpdate() will generate then how do i know? suppose without using SQL server profiler how can i hook AddOrUpdate() function in code which write or dupm the sql to console generate by  AddOrUpdate() function....any idea??

Comment: is there any site which show the feature added in EF version wise. suppose AddOrUpdate() added in EF version 4.3. so what other feature has been introduce in prev or next version in EF. i want site which show or discuss EF related feature version wise with example code & details. please guide if u have any idea. thanks

Comment: plzz see this code. / check by Primary key
context.Contacts.AddOrUpdate(_Contacts) u said it would check by PK but if there is more than one PK i mean composite PK is there...the how it will handle?